# jquery or javascript image onclick div fadein/ link onlcick div fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to make an image onclick function with a fadein hidden div the problem is I don't really know jquery or javascript all that well.  I have searched to try to do it in css but i heard it's buggy as hell and I don't understand enough of it js/jq to piece together what code i need and where it should go.

Basically what i want is this:
  you click on an image, the image fades in the hidden div, and preferably darkens the background (kind of like shadowbox would) then on the click of the close link within the hidden div, the div fades out and the background goes back to normal.

Right now I have the normal div with the image to be clicked, the hidden div, and the links set up.

I know it can be done, I'm just having a hell of a time figuring it out.  Please help?

::UPDATED CODE TO REFLECT JS CHANGES::

HTML-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title Goes Here</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content=" Enter Metatags" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">Shadowbox.init();
    </script></head>

    <body bgcolor="#547FA1">
    <div id="content">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="holder"><a href="#"><img src="images/openimage2.jpg" alt="open" width="1200" height="645" border="0" usemap="#Map" /></a>
      </img></div> 
      <div class="shadowdisc">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <font size=4 color=#999><p align=center>Content for Hidden Div.</p>
     <p align=center>Here is more content</p>
     <br /><br />
     <p align=center>Finishing the content here</p>
      <p>
      <p>
      <p align=center><a href="welcome.html">ENTER</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com">EXIT</a></p>
    <p>
   <p>
     <p align=right><a href="#">Close</a>
     </font>   
      </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body
    </html>
```

CSS-

```
      #content{
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url(bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(1%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
background-attachment: fixed
color: #5B5B5B;
           }



     #wrapper{
width: 1200px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 1100px;
           }


      #holder{
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
top: 150px;
background-color: #E3E3E3;
height: 594px;
           }

    .shadowdisc{
width: 900px;
background-image: url(images/disbg.png);
position: relative;
bottom: 400px;
border: 1px solid #999;
left: 148px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;
           }
</style>
```

Javascript

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
    <script>
      $(function () { // Onload

        $("#showImage").click(function () {
          $("#shadowdisc").fadeIn(1000);
       });

        $("#closeLink").click(function () {
          $("#shadowdisc").fadeOut(1000);
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Post what you've done so far

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, why don't you use an existing jQuery plugin like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)?

Comment: Does colorbox do hidden divs?  My understanding was that most/all of the /box plugins did images/media only.

Comment: The jQuery documentation has examples you can almost directly copy and paste for what you want to do: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Scroll down and look at the demos.

Comment: Adrien- I've seen countless examples, and I still don't understand how to apply it to my situation.  I'm obviously totally clueless when it comes to the functions and how they work.  It's like...I know which ones I'm supposed to use, but I don't know where they go/ what order/ or in relation to my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SGktV/1/) how to do it with JQuery and a little bit of CSS.

**HTML**

```
<button id="showButton">Show Panel</button>
<div id="hiddenPanel" class="hidden">
  <p>I'm a hidden div</p>
  <button id="closeButton">close me</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    opactiy: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  $(function () { // Onload

    $("#showButton").click(function () {
      $("#hiddenPanel").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#closeButton").click(function () {
       $("#hiddenPanel").fadeOut(1000);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't really work.  I'm still not getting it.  I tried substituting buttonId for my imageId, and my div id for my already hidden div, and closeButton for my close link id and then put the JQ with open/close tags in the header and the body of my html and it still hasn't worked.

Comment: See updated answer. You can load it as part of the page in a script block or as a separate JS file.

Comment: added changes to the code to reflect your answer.  the preview still isn't working right.

Comment: What is the problem/error? Can you create a JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: no error, the hidden div won't show on click of the image.  I tried to do a jsfiddle but i don't know how to add images into it....??

Comment: The problem is that your image does not have an id showImage and your #shadowdisc is not an id but a class like this .shadowdisc. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8bpdm/

Comment: Tried this... jsbin.com/avarat/1

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/omefob/1/)**</kbd>

```
<div id="lightbox"></div>
<img class="thumb" src="img1.jpg" alt="" />   
<img class="thumb" src="img2.jpg" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
h2, p{padding:30px;}

#lightbox{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left;0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
}
#lightbox > img{
  position:relative;
  height:400px;  
  top:50%;
  margin:-200px auto;
  display:inline;
  box-shadow:0 3px 25px #000, 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  width:auto;
}


.thumb{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  width:180px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQ:

```
$('.thumb').click(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#lightbox').append( '<img src="'+src+'"/>' ).fadeTo(800,1);

});

$('#lightbox').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo(800,0, function(){
    $(this).empty().hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: I liked your example, but I couldn't understand it.  I'd love to get the background dim to work on mine.